# How to set gallery in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am new in android.in my application gallery widget are completely run in portrait mode but that is not properly show in landscape mode.in which i am using switch case for portrait and landscape mode in on create method.

my code is below.

```
public class ViewAppGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    // take an array of integer type and set its value
    Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.gallery_photo_19, R.drawable.gallery_photo_20,
            R.drawable.gallery_photo_21, R.drawable.gallery_photo_22, R.drawable.gallery_photo_23,
            R.drawable.gallery_photo_24, R.drawable.gallery_photo_25,R.drawable.gallery_photo_15,R.drawable.gallery_photo_16,R.drawable.gallery_photo_18,
            R.drawable.gallery_photo_9,R.drawable.gallery_photo_10,R.drawable.gallery_photo_11,R.drawable.gallery_photo_12,R.drawable.gallery_photo_26,
            R.drawable.gallery_photo_27, R.drawable.gallery_photo_28,R.drawable.gallery_photo_29, R.drawable.gallery_photo_30
            };

    int lastOrientation = 0;
    private int imageWidth;
    private ImageView leftArrowImageView;
    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;
    private ImageView rightArrowImageView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        switch (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
        {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // take an instance of Gallery


             DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
             getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


             final ExtendedGallery g = (ExtendedGallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
           //  g.setScrollingEnabled(false);
             MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams)g.getLayoutParams();
             mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels/2 +60 ), mlp.topMargin,
                         mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin);
            // set adapter to gallery calling ImageAdapter class
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mImageIds));
            // set onItemClickListener on gallery Object





            g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds [position]);

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // onItemClick show Message
                    //selectedImagePosition =position;
                    if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3) {

                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                                       } 
                    else if (selectedImagePosition == 0)
                                       {

                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));
                                       }
                    else if (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1) 
                                       {
                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));

                                       }

                                   }
                              });

            g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                    selectedImagePosition = pos;

                    if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3) 
                                        {

                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                                        } 
                    else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) 
                                        {

                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));
                                        }
                    else if (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1 )
                                        {
                                        leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                        rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));

                                        }


                                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                                                    }
                        });


            leftArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
            rightArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);

            leftArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                                    if (selectedImagePosition > 2) {

                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;

                                                    }
                                                    else if(selectedImagePosition == 2)
                                                    {
                                                                            --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                            --selectedImagePosition;
                                                    }
                                                    else if(selectedImagePosition == 1)
                                                    {
                                                                            --selectedImagePosition;
                                                    }


                                                     g.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                                                    //g.scrollBy(20, 0);

                                                        //leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));



                                                }
                                            });

            rightArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (selectedImagePosition < mImageIds.length-3 )
                                            {
                                                ++selectedImagePosition;
                                                ++selectedImagePosition;
                                                ++selectedImagePosition;
                                            }

                                            g.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);

                                            //rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                                        }
                                    });



          break;
        case   Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:


            setContentView(R.layout.land);
             //setContentView(R.layout.main);
                // take an instance of Gallery


                 DisplayMetrics metrics1 = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics1);


                 final ExtendedGallery g1 = (ExtendedGallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
               //  g.setScrollingEnabled(false);
                 MarginLayoutParams mlp1 = (MarginLayoutParams)g1.getLayoutParams();
                 mlp1.setMargins(-(metrics1.widthPixels/2 +60 ), mlp1.topMargin,
                             mlp1.rightMargin, mlp1.bottomMargin);
                // set adapter to gallery calling ImageAdapter class
                g1.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter1(this, mImageIds));
                // set onItemClickListener on gallery Object





                g1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        ImageView imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds [position]);

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // onItemClick show Message
                        //selectedImagePosition =position;
                        if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3) {

                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                                           } 
                        else if (selectedImagePosition == 0)
                                           {

                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));
                                           }
                        else if (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1) 
                                           {
                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));

                                           }

                                       }
                                  });

                g1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                        selectedImagePosition = pos;

                        if (selectedImagePosition > 0 && selectedImagePosition <mImageIds.length - 3) 
                                            {

                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));

                                            } 
                        else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) 
                                            {

                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_enabled));
                                            }
                        else if (selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 3 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 2 || selectedImagePosition == mImageIds.length - 1 )
                                            {
                                            leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_enabled));
                                            rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));

                                            }


                                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                                                        }
                            });


                leftArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
                rightArrowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);

                leftArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                                        if (selectedImagePosition > 2) {

                                                                                    --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                                    --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                                    --selectedImagePosition;

                                                        }
                                                        else if(selectedImagePosition == 2)
                                                        {
                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;
                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;
                                                        }
                                                        else if(selectedImagePosition == 1)
                                                        {
                                                                                --selectedImagePosition;
                                                        }


                                                         g1.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);
                                                        //g.scrollBy(20, 0);

                                                            //leftArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_left_disabled));



                                                    }
                                                });

                rightArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (selectedImagePosition < mImageIds.length-3 )
                                                {
                                                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                                                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                                                    ++selectedImagePosition;
                                                }

                                                g1.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, false);

                                                //rightArrowImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_right_disabled));
                                            }
                                        });







          break;

        default:
            try {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected orientation enumeration returned");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          break;
        }




                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a main.xml in layout and layout-land folder under 'res' directory.
2. Make sure you have different alignment in landscape to align with your need.
3. Android system will choose it run time which the orientation is getting changed.